# Create a vector of features by droping specific columns Spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I use `VectorAssembler` to create a vector of features from >2000 columns so that I can run a PCA on it. I would normally explicitly state which columns need to be included in the feature vector:

```
val dataset = (spark.createDataFrame(
Seq((0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.7, 1.9), (1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.7, 2.9), (2, 3.2, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7))
).toDF("id", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"))

 val assembler = (new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols(Array("f2", "f3"))
.setOutputCol("featureVec"))
```

But in case of more than 2000 columns how can I specify that all columns except for "id" and "f1" should be included?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One of the easiest way is to get all the column names, convert to a set and subtract the columns you don't need and again use it as an array** as

```
val datasetColumnsToBeUsed = dataset.columns.toSet - "id" - "f1" toArray
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
val assembler = (new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array(datasetColumnsToBeUsed: _*))
  .setOutputCol("featureVec"))
```

And another easiest way is to use `filter` on *column names* as

```
val columnNames = dataset.columns
val datasetColumnsToBeUsed = columnNames.filterNot(x => Array("id", "f1").contains(x))
```

And use it as above

Comment: @vanja_65, I have added yet another easy way :)

Comment: Great! Thanks ;-)